# How to add rel="preload" in Wordpress Porto Theme css, can't find css link

Tags: css, wordpress, preload

I've been running Google Page Speed Inisght and two of my themes css failed because of not having rel="preload" attribute. The problem is I can't find the link anywhere in my themes php files.

Site is [www.gruppogreggiurbani.com.ar](http://www.gruppogreggiurbani.com.ar)

[image]